# Controlling page-breaks with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm building a web app that is basically a giant form which then generates a document for printing.

Is it possible to define where the page will break purely with HTML/CSS?

For instance, could I define that a certain element must always appear on top of a page when printing?

Comment: what do you mean with pagebreak? When you print the page? On screen you should think about splitting the form into different pages with some pagination tecnique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [page-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) css properties.

```
h1 {
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

Also I can recommend some general advice and useful tips for printing stylesheets in [this Smashing Magazine article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/).